# How should one express the idea 'in the opinion of Japanese'?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiom-request

If I want to express the idea 'in the opinion of Japanese', which of the following is correct?

1. In Japanese's eyes, ...
2. In Japanese eyes, ...
3. In the eyes of Japanese, ...

Is there anything I should pay extra attention to?

Comment: If you are referring to the Japanese people as a whole, (3) is the best but it should have **the** Japanese.

Comment: Could you complete the sample sentence, in the question, please? It would make it easier for users to say whether (2) or (3) is the better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the options you've put forward, (3) is the closest to being idiomatic to my ear. As @Peter has pointed out, it should read

> In the eyes of *the* Japanese, ...

However, unless the circumstances are unusual, I would recommend against using this construction in this context, for the following reasons:

1. If we are talking about a group of people or an organization (call it/them A), we generally only use the construction "in the eyes of A" when A is *unanimous* in their opinion or view of something. Unless we are talking about a group like "the government," "the court," or "the jury" where there genuinely is only one opinion, the phrase is usually qualified or nuanced: "in the eyes of the majority of scholars," "some viewers," "most women." I would **qualify your statement**: Unless Japanese people are in *unanimous* or *almost unanimous* agreement about something, I would say **most Japanese people**. (Note: in this case the phrase is "in the eyes of most Japanese people," *not* "in the eyes of the most Japanese people")
2. As a matter of tone, when talking about a group of people of a single nationality, race, or ethnicity, the construction "the XYZ" should be used with care. It is certainly more formal in the case of nationality: "the Japanese" is more formal than "Japan" (which can also refer to the citizenry) which is more formal than "Japanese people" which is more formal than "people from Japan." In the case of race, you can get in trouble for using this construction: "The blacks" and "the whites" are both inappropriate in formal writing (in the US), and can be offensive. Unless your context is quite formal, or you are talking about a matter of international diplomacy, I would **avoid the construction** "the Japanese" as a matter of building good habits. An alternative might be **Japanese people**.

I'd also like to add that there's nothing wrong with simply saying

> In the opinion of [most/some/many] Japanese people...

or

> [Most/Some/Many] Japanese people think...